# Does performance issues occur with increase in changesets?

Tags: liquibase

My company uses liquibase to keep track of database changes. Everyday around 100 new changesets are being added. From what I understand for already executed changesets liquibase computes checksum again and compares it with checksum in databasechangelog table to see whether checksum has changed and gives checksum issue if it is changed.

So after few months when I have large number of changesets already executed, If I add a new changeset doesn't this process of computing checksum of already executed changesets and comparing them make the execution of new changesets slower or cause any performance related issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never stumbled across this kind of performance issues with liquibase.

But I guess your question raises a couple of more questions:

- what do you consider to be "slower"?
- when performance starts to become an issue and is it really an issue?
- maybe something's wrong with your application's architecture?

Anyway, comparing checksums against DATABASECHANGELOG table shouldn't take a lot of time - it could be couple of seconds, if you have lots and lots of changeSets.

According to liquibase documentation:

> Other times, the problem is that liquibase update is taking too long.
>   Liquibase tries to be as efficient as possible when comparing the
>   contents of the DATBASECHANGELOG table with the current changelog file
>   and even if there are thousands of already ran changeSets, an “update”
>   command should take just seconds to run.

But if these seconds **really** make an issue, then consider reading this article:
[Trimming ChangeLog Files](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/trimming_changelogs.html)

Comment: I don't have any performance issues as of now but I am asking in future when there are large number of changesets would it result in any performance issues. Anyway your explanation answers my question

Comment: Great! If it answers your question, please consider marking it as an answer